# pyminifier not updating the same file rather printing code on stdout

Tags: python-3.x, minify

I  want to minify the code using pyminifier which is successfull but I don't want pyminifier to print the code on stdout so that then I have to copy paste that code again to the file  or to some other directory .How can I use pyminifier update the same python file with minified code.

```
pyminifier a.py --destdir=a.py
```

the above command gives error as a.py is not found  and creates the updated code in .minified directory with a.py file. But it would want the same file i.e  a.py  code to get update on runnning pyminfier command.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it ,if you want to update and run pyminfier on multiple files then using follwing command  you can achieve that  . i am in the directory where these files  a.py and inserts.py are located and want them to get these files updated after running pyminifier.

pyminifier --destdir=./ a.py inserts.py

Second way is to run for the single file instead of multiple files then you can command like this  :

```
pyminifier --outfile=./a.py a.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows,

The easiest way I found is by doing this from command prompt:

```
C:\>pyminifier main.py > main2.py
```

main2.py will be our new file containing the code based on the amount of options (run pyminifier for the options) we specified to pyminifier.

We can take main2.py file and rename it to whatever we want and use it.

main.py, our original file, would remain unchanged.